# IIS - Website - Browse - Parse Error Message: an error occurred while parsing entity name : line 5 position 51

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-config

- Created a C# Rest API in .NET 4.7 +;
- The API got publish from visual studio;
- The API got installed as an IIS service;
- The API run as a swagger Service and in can point Postman and play with it.
- I have tested the API in different machines (Window Server 2016)  successfully
- In a specific machine (Window Server 2016)  with same .NET version it would not run throwing's - the same error :

[image]

- .NET version

[image]

If I then remove that section (which however is working fine in another machine) it will still throw the same error for another Entity Name: Line 5 Position 51;

- I have tried to remove some entities in the web.config file
- reinstall IIS.
- tried to log for event viewer log files and iis log file too - with no luck.

Here when changing the lines in the web config still having the same line 5 position 51 Error

[image]

Here the XML Web Config File:

[image]

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="common">
<section name="logging" 
type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
</sectionGroup>
<section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
</configSections>
<appSettings file="..\..\AppSecrets.config">
<add key="cors" value="localhost;localhost2; ;" />
<add key="connection" value="web" />
<add key="waitandretry" value="3" />
<add key="circuitbreaker" value="3" />
<add key="circuitbreakertime" value="5" />
<add key="apikey" value="xxxxxx" />
</appSettings>
<common>
<logging>
<factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, 
Common.Logging.NLog4411">
<arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
</factoryAdapter>
</logging>
</common>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
internalLogFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sms\MyAPI\logs\InnerLog.txt" 
internalLogLevel="Error" autoReload="true">
<extensions>
<add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog" />
</extensions>
<targets>
<target xsi:type="File" name="log" 
fileName="${basedir}\logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log" 
layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
<target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" source="testlogging" 
log="Application" 
layout="${message}${newline}${exception:format=ToString}" />
</targets>
<rules>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="log" />
<logger name="*" minLevel="Error" writeTo="eventlog" />
</rules>
</nlog>
<system.web>
<trace enabled="true" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
</system.web>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxxx" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxxx" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />  
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.Owin" 
publicKeyToken="xxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="xxxxxx" 
culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.8.1.0" newVersion="4.8.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Autofac.Integration.WebApi" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Autofac.Integration.Owin" 
publicKeyToken="xxxxx" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" 
type="
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform. 
CSharpCodeProvider, 
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx" warningLevel="4" 
compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" 
type= 
"Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, 
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx" warningLevel="4" 
compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 
/define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
<remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<defaultDocument>
<files>
<add value="/swagger" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The first `<compiler>` tag misses a `"` after `type=`. You'd better use an XML formatter against your `web.config` which usually reports typical issues to you.

Comment: i had issues copying an xml here - the web congif might miss a quote here but it does not in the server.

Comment: The xml is fine - i would not post if it was a double quote issue -  please need help still

Comment: The actual file content (and its encoding) matters a lot, as the line numbers show in your screenshot are rather weird. `<configuration>` should be on line 1 or 2.

Comment: I am going to add the actual screenshot of the web config maybe is easier to identify the issue... unfortunately StackOvverflow had me changes the whole file content as it would accept copy/paste.

Comment: screenshot added - maybe this is easier to see.

Comment: I checked web.config and I'm sure that it has no problem. If you have another server with IIS, please test the application on another server. Or you can reinstall IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Check ampersand characters in your : AppSecrets.config sometimes the error number refers to that file